# how to initialize result in method?

Tags: java

result isn't initialized, how to do it in this method?(to preserve the functionality of the code)

```
static int maxNumbers(int r, int s) {

    int result;
    int[] rk = new int[r];

    for (int i = 0; i < rk.length; i++) {
        if (s > 1) {
            rk[i] = (s - 1) + 1;
            s--;
        } else if (s == 1) {
            rk[i] = (s + 1) + 1;
            s = 0;
        } else {
            rk[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rk.length; i++) {
        result = rk[0] * 2 * rk[i++]*2;
    }


    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ur method needs to be called somewhere?

Comment: what's the functionality of this function?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if r==0?

Comment: @KickButtowski: I don't see how that's relevant. The OP is asking about a problem *within* the method, not how to call it.

Comment: *"to preserve the functionality of the code"* - The code currently doesn't compile, so at this time there *is no* functionality of the code.  What you need to decide is what you *want* this code to do.  What the compiler is essentially asking you is, what should this method return if `r` is less than or equal to `0`.  Whatever that intended return value is, that's what you'd assign to that variable when you declare the variable.

Comment: @jon skeet thank u. U r right

Answer (score 2):

For the integer primitive and regarding your example you can simply write `int result = -1;`.

Although you set your `result` variable in the 2nd `for` loop, the compiler cannot guarantee that this `for` loop actually loops and therefore the variable will be set.

So in the end you should check the result of the method.